# Importing posts from old website to new conflicting post ID's?

Tags: database, import, id

I am wondering when I am importing posts from my old site into my new website, which has already some posts in it. Do the imported posts get a new ID or do they overrule the existing posts ID's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I can confirm that the imported post will get a new unique ID if (and only if) there already is an existing/conflicting ID in the target database.***

Given a post to be imported with an ID of `7579` (represented in the WXR export file as `<wp:post_id>7579</wp:post_id>`) and an existing post with that exact same ID already in the target database, the generated ID for the imported post was `7583`.

*(As far why `7583`? I would have thought auto increment but `7579` was an existing post, `7580` a revision of that post and `7581` a draft of some sort. So not exactly sure why `7582` was skipped.)*

Comment: Does it handles posts IDs in  `wp_term_relationships` table?. We may lose that relationship between posts and terms.

Comment: From my experience posts are OK with relationships. But attachments collide.

Answer (score 0):

The imported posts will get a new ID.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer. How do you know that?

Comment: I exported my database to give it a try and in the generated .sql file I have INSERT INTO `wp_posts` VALUES (1900,2,'2014-08-18 17:10:21' etc. where 1900 is the ID of the post. So I'm not entirely sure that a new ID is assigned if you import back when post or page with ID 1900 is still in the database. I would do it with http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post if the database already has data.